# Change loop that overwrites data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R and I apply a function to it so it returns another data frame, and I do that successively, with different inputs. A way to do this is the following:

```
output_df <- df %>% 
    modify_df(input_1) %>% 
    modify_df(input_2) %>% 
    modify_df(input_3) %>% 
    modify_df(input_4)
```

This is not very scalable and I want to do it in a more programmatic way.
I guess I can also do something like:

```
for(input in input_list){
  output_df <- modify_df(output_df, input)
}
```

But I don't like doing for loops in R. Would this alternative work?

```
output_df <- lapply(input, function(x) modify_df(output_df, x))
```

Comment: should work, try running. `input` should be a list here. If you want a df in output then you can also try `sapply`. `lapply` returns list.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: Theres nothing fundamentally wrong with a properly done `for` loop in R, because you are having an output of the prior be part of the next in a sequence you should probably not use `lapply()`.

Comment: This is where a MCVE comes in useful: you could try it yourself.

Comment: You could try `Reduce`, but without a clearer example its hard to say. `Reduce(modify_df, list(df, input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do it that way (see example below, which simply multiplies the data frame by a series of numbers – `1:5` is my vector of inputs, in this case), but I would favour a loop in this situation.

```r
df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10)

modify_df <- function(input){
  df <<- df * input
}

invisible(lapply(1:5, modify_df))

print(df)
#>     A    B
#> 1 120  720
#> 2 240  840
#> 3 360  960
#> 4 480 1080
#> 5 600 1200
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

---

#### In response to the comment below

[`<<-`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html) is modifying `df` in the parent environment, rather than the function's environment. `df` is modified as a side effect of calling the function, rather than being returned directly by the function, which can make life difficult when debugging. Using a loop, however, makes it clear what's happening as the function returns the modified data frame.

Comment: Also worth explaining exactly what `<<-` is doing and why a for loop is safer.

Comment: @zacdav Updated.